# Cartesian Product Proof for Three sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have a homework question I need help with. I need to show that if $A \times B$ is a subset of $B \times C$ then prove A is a subset of C.

Comment: Hi, welcome to MSE! I prettified your post -- you can click the 'edit' button to see the code. What are your thoughts about this problem so far?

Answer (score 1):

What you're basically trying to prove is that $$((A \times B) \subseteq (B \times C)) \implies A \subseteq C$$ To show subset inclusion the methods are almost always the same. Assume $((A \times B) \subseteq (B \times C))$.
Let $x_1 \in A$ and $x_2 \in B$ be arbitrary. This means that $(x_1,x_2) \in A \times B$ and that $(x_1,x_2) \in B \times C$. Now we know that $x_1 \in A,B$ and $x_2 \in B,C$. I won't finish the proof from here because it should be obvious what happens next.

Answer (score 0):

Use the fact that
$$
A \times B\subset C\times D\iff A\subset C\land B\subset D
$$
So in this problem, we have
$$
A \times B\subset B\times C\implies A\subset B\land B\subset C \implies A\subset C
$$
Last one is the transitivity of inclusion of set.

Answer (score 0):

This is true iff $B\ne \emptyset$. If $B=\emptyset$ then both products are empty and $B, C$ can be *anything*. So assume $B\ne \emptyset$.

If $A=\emptyset$ then $A\subseteq C$. If $C=\emptyset$ then $B\times C =\emptyset$, so $A\times B =\emptyset$ and therefore either $A=\emptyset$ or $B =\emptyset$; thus $A=\emptyset\subseteq C$.

Otherwise, all of $A,B,C \ne\emptyset$. Now you can use the projection functions $p_1\colon (x,y)\mapsto x$, $p_2\colon (x,y)\mapsto y$. By nonemptiness of $A,B,C$, the projection functions are surjections. If $A\times B\subseteq B\times C$, then $A = p_1(A\times B) \subseteq p_1(B\times C) = B$, and similarly $B = p_2(A\times B) \subseteq p_2(B\times C) = C$, so $A\subseteq C$.